# How to fit a multivariate gaussian distribution with missing entries?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, bayesian

I am trying to fit a K-dimensional multivariate gaussian distribution (ie. learn mu and Sigma) from data missing completely at random. On the internet, I have found unbiased solutions via EM, as well as a few older, fairly complicated methods. I am curious if anyone knows why "the obvious solution" is never mentioned. By the "obvious solution" I mean simply taking the mean of all observed entries (to learn mu), & the correlation amongst observed pairs of variables, and the variance of individual variables (to learn Sigma).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you post links to the non-obvious solutions?